# How can I upgrade my firmware if I don't have macos installed?

Tags: install, upgrade, firmware

I'm a Linux guru and have installed Windows 7 dual boot with ubuntu for my work computer but to be able to use all 8gb worth of ram I need to upgrade my firmware. Any ideas?

I'm using a macbook A1342 (mid 2010)

Comment: It would help if you included the model of Mac you have in your original question.

Comment: Done, it's a A1342

Comment: get external drive. Recovery partition was added about that time.  command + r to see if you get into the recovery partition. Install on the external drive. To boot the external drive, Hold down the option key to get into the startup manager.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Firmware update are bundled with OS X/macOS updates. I think you'd have to reinstall macOS and update it to the latest supported version. Assuming you don't want to reinstall and setup both OS again, you should be fine to swap our your HD temporarily for another, do the macOS updates, then put your other HD back in.